# function returns relating columns with the corresponding column removed

Tags: r, multiple-columns

This is my code so far:

```
record <- function(input, string){ 
filter(input, input$race == string |
          input$flag == string)
```

}

Please help

Comment: 1) With `filter` you don't need `recordings$` only `V1` and `V2` will do it. 2) You filter on 2 columns, what *corresponding column* should be removed? 3) Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(recordings)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(recordings, 20))`. And the expected output too, please.

Comment: For example, if the string matches a value in V1 then the whole column  V1 shouldn't be displayed after using the function.

Comment: Where can i find all the codes to display my problem properly to answer your question @RuiBarradas

Comment: All the codes you need is the function `dput()` as I have posted in the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `which`. Using data from @RuiBarradas:

```
set.seed(1234)  
recordings <- data.frame(V1 = sample(LETTERS, 10),
                         V2 = sample(LETTERS, 10),
                         V3 = letters[1:10], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

records <- function(recordings, string){ 

  rws <- which(recordings == string, arr.ind = TRUE)[,1]

  cls <- which(recordings == string, arr.ind = TRUE)[,2]

  recordings <- recordings[rws, -cls, drop = FALSE]

  return(recordings)

}
```

For `A`, it would return:

```
records(recordings, "A")

  V2 V3
7  F  g
```

For `X`:

```
records(recordings, "X")

  V3
4  d
5  e
```

This assumes that no value is present in all columns.

If you need to only know the corresponding row values:

```
records <- function(recordings, string){ 

  return(which(recordings == string, arr.ind = TRUE)[,1])

}

records(recordings, "X")
[1] 4 5
```

Comment: It worked almost but I need to get it like 1. 2. 3. and not which rows they are. Like a subset

Comment: I think it would really help if you provide the expected output, thanks.

Comment: also edited my question with some screenshots what i need and not need

Comment: I'm not sure about your edit, as e.g. there is w in your expected output while it is not in initial dataframe, etc. However, if you only need the corresponding row numbers then see my edit.

Comment: it was just a random letter haha, Your first code was good except from the part that your are just locating where in the dataset is the matching value with the rows. What i need is not only locating but also show all the rows which are corresponding to your input in a "new" dataframe

Comment: Sorry, but still unclear. Perhaps you could show us with the dataset from Rui what would be the expected output, it'll be easier.

Comment: Check, i edited the question with snapshots with actually what needs to be done.

Comment: I actually think my code works with this type of question.

Comment: It does in a way but i need to replicate the given output on the question

Answer (score 0):

See if the following is what you want.

First I will make up a dataset, since you have not posted one.

```
set.seed(1234)    # Make the results reproducible
recordings <- data.frame(V1 = sample(LETTERS, 10),
                         V2 = sample(letters, 10),
                         V3 = sample(4, 10, TRUE))
```

Now the function.

```
records <- function(DF, string){
  inx <- DF == string
  i <- apply(inx, 1, function(x) Reduce('||', x))
  DF[i, which(colSums(!inx) == nrow(DF)), drop = FALSE]
}

records(recordings, "A")
#  V2 V3
#7  f  3

records(recordings, "x")
#  V1 V3
#5  S  1
```

Comment: Thanks for making up a dataset. But it is not the answer. I need it like: if the string matches a value in a Column, that it returns all corresponding rows with that value but does not return the Column. So for example: 

records(recordings, "A") should return all corresponding rows to "A" but does not Return the column in which "A" is found. It needs to return all other rows with columns what matches. 

Does this clarify my question?

Comment: @user10835346 I believe this solves it. At least it's what I could make of the question linked in your question. It is very important to know that the data in the columns cannot have equal values, so I have changed the example dataset.

Comment: I need to replicate exact the given output as in the Question screenshot.  So, unfortunally it does not work

Comment: @user10835346 Please reread my first comment to the question. Images are a really bad way of posting data (and code) because there is not much we can do with them. `dput()` is **the best way** of posting data.

Comment: @user10835346 Changed the function, once again. See if this is it.